# php.ini does not exist

Tags: 16.04, php, php7

There is no php.ini after installing php (7.1) on ubuntu 16.04

I installed php using `apt install php`. I already tried to find the php.ini using the find command, but there is no file called php.ini anywhere.

Comment: If one of the below answers works for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark icon.  If none works for you, please edit your question and add a postscript to say so.

Answer (score 4):

I recently setup a wordpress server and ran into this same issue.

I used `apt-get install php`

Everything seemed to be normal except I could not find the php.ini file either. That file is usually located in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

My solution, and I guess is also your solution would be that apache mod didn't get installed for php. So all you need to run is `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

I also bounced apache just to be safe, but then my php.ini file was then located where I expected it in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 3):

Try using the command `php --ini`. Since you're running command line, it won't necessarily show you the config files you may be looking for (apache, nginx, etc), but it will hopefully get you on the right path.

When I run it I see:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
```

Which tells me if I'm looking for Apache files, I can find the rest up one directory from there:

```
$ ls /etc/php/7.0/
apache2  cli  fpm  mods-available
```

If all else fails, and you're able to browse to a .php file on the server, create a file using [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) like this and take a look to see what ini files are in use:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use the `locate` command instead. Here is my output:

```
subroot@subroot:~$ find php.ini
find: ‘php.ini’: No such file or directory

subroot@subroot:~$ locate php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini.ucf-dist
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini.ucf-old
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini.ucf-dist
/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production.cli
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.cli
/usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-production.cli
subroot@subroot:~$
```

Type `man find` and `man locate` for the difference between the two commands.

Answer (score 0):

You may have passed the wrong options to `find`, just like Parto did in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921485/php-ini-does-not-exist#921697).

Try this `find` command:

```
find / -iname '*php.ini*'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the php module just install it.

```
sudo apt install php
```

php is not bundled with apache out of the box.
You may also have to additional steps. Check here: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/installing-php-for-apache-on-ubuntu/